# how to run a php file from another server?

Tags: php, video-processing, remote-server, cron-task

i am trying to do a video converter that grabs some files from a html form and converts them.

i would like to do the conversion on another server, `.11`,  since i don't want to overload the main server `.10`

i can set up a network folder between the two servers, `/media`, and have a `convert.php` on `.11` that will run the ffmpeg command.

if i run that php file from `.10` then will the video conversion process take resources from `.11` or from `.10` ? Seems to me that `.10` will be affected even if the php file is on `.11`.

I could do a cron job, but i really don't want to.

For this project i am using zend framework

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

thanks

Comment: If you run the PHP file on .10 it will consume resources on .10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely recommend implementing a Queue for these kind of tasks. Your queue could be simply a MySQL database that maintains a list of outstanding tasks. The workers can check this database for any tasks to be run.

This will provide you with far more flexibility in terms of scaling up. Tomorrow, if you decide to add two more worker servers/systems, they will fit seamlessly into the queue-model.

Comment: so i still need a cron job that looks in the database periodically. Am i getting this wrong? can u explain a bit more?

Comment: Yes, you'd need a cron job that invokes the worker script. If the worker script finds an outstanding task, it consumes it. Otherwise, it dies.

Comment: I know you said you want to avoid cron jobs, but embracing them will allow you to build a far more scalable system.

Comment: i could then just make a cron job that will look in the `/media` folder for any new files, convert them, then move them to another folder

Comment: Sure, if after conversion you remove the file from the /media folder, you could use that as your queue as well.